# How to format the time coloumn in KendoGrid in the right timezones?

Tags: jquery, timezone, kendo-grid

I have a kendoGrid, I have to format the following date:

```
var time = Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time);
```

to this format:

```
Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Also, the dates can be in multiple formats like PST, IST and all other different world timezones. So basically abbreviating the timezone part.

I have already tried 
        `kendo.toString(new Date(data), 'MM-dd-yyyy');`

And different variations of it, but no luck yet!

Comment: You haven't thought this through, provided enough information, or demonstrated you've researched the problem space.  Recognize that not all time zones *have* valid abbreviations.  Also, the strings you get back from a `Date` object's `.toString()` function are meant to be human readable, not machine parsable.  They are implementation specific, and localized.   (Also, what you wrote isn't valid javascript unless you put it in quotation marks here - please be precise.)

Comment: What do you mean, I have thought through this? I have in fact done my research thoroughly. What I am asking is that if you have the date format in the described format and want to abbreviate the timezone, what do you do? I have not put my code samples. It is more of a conceptual question, Can we do that with kendo or not? And I need it to be human readable and not machine parseable.

Comment: As I said, not every time zone *has* any valid abbreviation.  Any list of time zone abbreviations you may find on the internet will have ambiguities and inventions, and is likely to disagree with other lists of time zone abbreviations you may find.  Also, you are not showing anything valid in that first line of code here.  Is it in fact a string? If so, put it in quotation marks so that it's valid JavaScript.  Is it in fact a `Date` object?  Then show how you construct it.

Comment: If it is indeed a string, try to explain where it originated from.  How did you get "Eastern Standard Time" into the string?  Was it another `Date` object and you did a `.toString()` somewhere?  How do you expect all the possible variations of time zone descriptions to be interpreted?  It's not a trivial problem.

Comment: And no - [Kendo's date formatting](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting#custom) does not provide for time zone abbreviations.  You could get closer to what you're looking for with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone), but I'd have to understand your exact input better before I could give an answer to that effect.

Comment: thanks for your comments!